# Delete a specific file with a shortcut key

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, macros, keyboard-shortcuts, coderush

Is there a way to delete a specific file or 2 files with a **shortcut key** in Visual Studio?
The path is will be a dynamic path of the current selected/active project.

That is no matter for me to use a 3rd party tool, macros, extensions, batch files, CodeRush or whatever (using some other Windows apps or ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a command and assign a shortcut to it with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension.

In the command, to get the project path for the active document window:

```
string projectFile=DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject.FileName;
```

To delete a file:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(path);
```

Comment: Nice +1, not sure how can I assign a shortcut then, will check the tool and the document.

Comment: Hello again Mr Vlaslov, I created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68325886/132239 which if you be interested, I like to know if your extension can help, (which I think so), or not? Thanks if you have a look and help me with that.