# Open a file in solution explorer with a relative path by a shortcut key

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

Is there a way to **select/open a file from the solution explorer** with a *shortcut key*?

In all my projects I have a file named **Note.txt,** it can be found in `Project\Info\Note.txt`.

Want to assign a shortcut that when we hit it, it **select and open the Note.txt of the current project**.

Using 3rd party tools are welcome.

---

If I know how to write the macro, etc with a tool, then we can set a shortcut for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    string projectFile = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject.FileName;
    string notePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(projectFile), @"Info\Note.txt");
    DTE.ItemOperations.OpenFile(notePath);
}
```

Comment: Nice, Thanks Mr. Sergey Vlasov, It doesn't select the file in the Solution Explorer, but will open it. It helped.